# LINQPad isn't finding embedded assembly

Tags: embedded-resource, linqpad, fusion

I have my own assembly where I've embedded some third party assemblies into the dll via the Vitivec Assemblies Embedder extension.  These third party assemblies are all used internally and not exposed outside of my assembly.

All works fine when running the assembly under asp.net scenario, however, in LINQPad, when I reference my dll in LINQPad, it gives me an 'assembly load/not found' error for the embedded assembly and I must include a reference the third party assembly as well (even though its usage is completely private within my assembly).

The error I get is:

> Could not load file or assembly '{Assmebly.Namespace}, Version=7.1.2.136, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=39c186f5904944ec' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Is LINQPad unable to work in this scenario?  I'd like to share my assembly and LINQPad script with others without having to also distribute the third party assembly that is already embedded into my assembly.

Comment: I suspect that LinqPad is overriding how assemblies are loaded in the same way that the Embedder is doing. And possibly interfering with it. I'd raise it as a support request with the author of LinqPad.

Comment: You might be able to script the Assembly.Load calls in the initializer of you assembly and load them from the resource streams.

Comment: Using `Assembly.Load(byte[])` fetch the `byte[]` from `new MemoryStream(ResourceManager.GetStream(name)).ToArray()`.

Comment: I did send a bug submission through the application, seems like he watches SO very often too, so I'm hoping he sees it here as well.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you disable assembly shadowing in Edit | Preferences | Advanced?

Comment: Under Preferences-Advanced-Execution, 'Do not shadow assembly references' was false when I originally posted.  I set to true just now and tested and got the same result.

Comment: Weird situation...Before testing the shadow setting, I was previously running with 3rd party assembly referenced.  I had to remove my 3rd party reference.  As I stated, it still failed.  I then set the setting back to false and then ran the script and it worked.  I checked references on my script and the 3rd party dll was still *not* referenced.  I ran it again and it still worked.  I closed and opened the script, and then I was back to the error again.